# How to insert GeoJson file into elastic Search cloud without logstach and CURL command?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to insert GeoJson file into elastic search cloud without logstach?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON is a simple json file which you can index in the ES by using CURL command

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/1' -d @geo.json
```

Sample geo.json

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```